# Crash on swift class init when using inline initializers

Tags: swift, class, swift3

I'm developing an application and I encountered a crash that I can't explain.

The library is fairly complex so I prepared a minimum example

```
struct Info {
  static let test = 1
}

class SuperCls<A> {}

class Cls<A>: SuperCls<A> {
  let v: Info.Type = Info.self
}

let v = Cls<Int>()
```

This code crashes when I alloc the class, in the very last line, with the following error

`file:///play.playground/: error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4403).`

I also tried this in an xcode project and the error is pretty much the same

I found a way to make this code works

```
struct Info {
  static let test = 1
}

class SuperCls<A> {}

class Cls<A>: SuperCls<A> {
  var v: Info.Type?

  override init() {
    v = Info.self
    super.init()
  }
}

let v = Cls<Int>()
```

Can someone tell me why this crash occurs?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
I also discovered that this works
struct Info {
  let test = 1
}

class SuperCls<A> {}

class Cls<A>: SuperCls<A> {
  let v = Info()
}

let v = Cls<Int>()
```

The problem seems to be related to the fact that I'm using `Info` as a type and accessing static information

Comment: "crash" is too little info, any error? any line? anything?

Comment: You're right, So it crashes when I instantiate the class, so the very last line. This is the error

`file:///play.playground/: error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4403).`

I tried also in a xcode project rather than a playground and the error is pretty much the same

(I update also the question)

Comment: @MauroBolis It doesn't crash in Xcode 8 beta4, also works with 2016-08-04 snapshot. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8 beta 5
It can be a bug introduced in this beta then

Comment: Bug in the beta. I've tried it in three versions of Xcode 8 now.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it seems that it is a bug in Xcode beta 5

Thanks for the help